# How to work with python list of lists?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a following sample list of lists:

```
In [] : list1
Out [] : 
[[1.0],
 [2.1],
 [3.3, 5.5, 0.69],
 [0.69, 0.9]]
```

I want to extract only the sublists where number of elements are equal and greater than 2 and want to store them in a data frame.

So, I expect a df something like below:

```
In [] : df
Out [] : 
        seq_no       items
            1        3.3 , 5.5, 0.69
            2        0.69, 0.9
```

Tried:

```
item for item in list1 where(len(item) >2)
```

shows error.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: You can filter the list of lists with a list comprehension.

Comment: *filter()* or list comprehension can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
In [755]: df = pd.DataFrame({'items': [x for x in list1 if len(x)>=2]})

In [756]: df
Out[756]:
              items
0  [3.3, 5.5, 0.69]
1       [0.69, 0.9]
```

Add, `seq_no`

```
In [759]: df['seq_no'] = df.index + 1

In [760]: df
Out[760]:
              items  seq_no
0  [3.3, 5.5, 0.69]       1
1       [0.69, 0.9]       2
```

If you need a string of comma separated `items`

```
In [769]: pd.DataFrame({'items': [', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in list1 if len(x)>=2]})
Out[769]:
            items
0  3.3, 5.5, 0.69
1       0.69, 0.9
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect !!

Answer (score 6):

Use `list comprehension` and for `seq` column `range`:

```
a = [x for x in L if len(x) >=2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'seq':range(1, len(a)+1), 'items':a}, columns=['seq','items'])
print (df)
   seq                items
0    1     [3.3, 5.5, 0.69]
1    2     [0.69, 0.9]
```

Comment: No, because it change order of columns.

Comment: Thank you so much, the first part is what I expect, all values under items column.

Answer (score 5):

You can store it in a `pd.Series` first, then filter and transform.

```
s = pd.Series(list1)
pd.DataFrame(s[s.str.len().ge(2)].tolist())

      0     1     2
0  0.00  0.50  0.69
1  0.69  0.88  1.00
2  1.00  1.10   NaN
3  1.10  2.00   NaN
4  2.00  2.50  2.90
```

---

And to join them

```
s = pd.Series(list1)
s[s.str.len().ge(2)].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)))

2      0.0, 0.5, 0.69
3     0.69, 0.88, 1.0
4            1.0, 1.1
8            1.1, 2.0
10      2.0, 2.5, 2.9
dtype: object
```

Comment: This does what I proposed but better! However I think OP wants them joined.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it (with a list comprehension):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series([sublist for sublist in list1 if len(sublist) >= 2])
```

Then you can add

```
df.index += 1
```

to adjust the start index if you'd like.